# getting undefined while trying to get selected radio value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<input type="radio" class="radioModal" value="Existing" name="SaveToGallery_rdGallery" id="SaveToGallery_rdGallery">

<input type="radio" class="radioModal" value="New" name="SaveToGallery_rdGallery" id="SaveToGallery_rdNewGallery">
```

When i am trying to get the selected radio value , i am getting undefined

```
alert($("input[@name='SaveToGallery_rdGallery']:checked").val())
```

jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/8F6Uq/

May i know where am i doing wrong

Sometimes i get value like "N"

Comment: Nothing is checked. So what do you expect it alerts?

Comment: select and run , you still get the same value

Comment: The `@` sign was deprecated in jQuery attr selectors many versions ago.

Comment: @kobe: of course since you re-run your code :) So the page is refreshed and the value will be unchecked again. Or I misunderstood you. Anyway check out my answer

Comment: @kobe - "select and run , you still get the same value" JSFiddle can't remember between page-loads that you selected a radio. However, adding the checked attr to one of the inputs (in the markup) and hitting "Run" alerts the value of the radio on which I put that attr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check a default value for it to work!

2. Change your selector to this:

```
alert($("input[name='SaveToGallery_rdGallery']:checked").val())
```

3. [**See it live**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/sTpfr/)

Comment: @kobe: Yes, if you want the alert to work, one of them should be explicitly checked at the loading time, otherwise it won't work. On the other hand, if you check one of them and in your code try to get the value of the checked one, it will return the value of the checked one, not undefined.

Comment: in the code or through debug i am not seeing the property checked attacthed to html , but it shows default checked for one of them

Comment: @kobe: Great! Feel free to accept an answer which solves your problem, mine or someone's else.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
alert($("input[name='SaveToGallery_rdGallery']:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, none of the radio buttons are checked. To do so you would need to add the checked attribute:

```
<input type="radio" style="vertical-align:top;margin-right:10px;margin-left:0;" class="radioModal" value="New" name="SaveToGallery_rdGallery" id="SaveToGallery_rdNewGallery" checked="checked">
```

Of course, in an actual page this would return whatever radio button was actually checked by the user.

Comment: run that fiddle by selecting some vlaue

Comment: You need to add both of the above answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').change(function(){
    alert($("input[@name='SaveToGallery_rdGallery']:checked").val())
});
```

Because when the page loads there is nothing selected. when you bind the `change` event and then alert it you can get the value

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is checked. So no elements are found.

If an element is checked it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/8F6Uq/1/

Or add some check:

```
if ($("input[@name='SaveToGallery_rdGallery']:checked") > 0) {
    // element found
}
```